# unround float based on required precision in python

Tags: python

In `python`, is there a method/library to unwrap/unround the number into a range of numbers, based on required precision?

Here is an example.

**Given** we have a number: `5.86`, with decimal precision/scale: `2` digits, **when** we unwrap/unround the number:

- to precision `3`, **then** range would be `[5.855; 5.864]` (diff: 9)
- to precision `4`, **then** range would be `[5.8550; 5.8649]` (diff: 99)

p.s. self-answer provided below

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing the question - I have managed to solve it using some custom made function. Maybe it's going to be of some use to somebody.

### Solution

```py
def split_value_into_range(number, needed_precision, current_precision = -1):
    # you can decide if you want to pass the current precision from outside or not..
    # probably doesn't really matter performance wise
    if current_precision == -1:
        # convert to string and remove trailing zeros from float
        numberStr = f'{number:g}'

        # get current precision
        scale = numberStr[::-1].find('.')
        current_precision = scale

    # get precision difference
    precision_diff = needed_precision - current_precision

    if precision_diff < 1:
        raise Exception("Operation not supported. NOTE: modify the function to suit your needs")

    # get number of 'digits' to substract and to add
    partial_substractor = 5 * (10 ** (precision_diff - 1))
    partial_adder = partial_substractor - 1

    # count how many `digits` are in range
    diff = partial_substractor + partial_adder

    denominator = 10 ** needed_precision
    substractor = partial_substractor / denominator
    adder = partial_adder / denominator

    min_range = round(number - substractor, needed_precision)
    max_range = round(number + adder, needed_precision)

    return min_range, max_range, diff

number = 5.86

min, max, diff = split_value_into_range(number, 3, 2)
print(f"min={min}, max={max}, diff={diff}")

min, max, diff = split_value_into_range(number, 4)
print(f"min={min}, max={max}, diff={diff}")

min, max, diff = split_value_into_range(number, 5)
print(f"min={min}, max={max}, diff={diff}")

min, max, diff = split_value_into_range(number, 6)
print(f"min={min}, max={max}, diff={diff}")
```

outputs

```
min=5.855, max=5.864, diff=9
min=5.855, max=5.8649, diff=99
min=5.855, max=5.86499, diff=999
min=5.855, max=5.864999, diff=9999
```

### Known limitations

if you want to keep the trailing zeros in float then you have to use the `Decimal`. Don't use `float`. :) In example above there is really no need in rounding the `min_range` as the python will dispose of the trailing zeros anyways.. Though, I wanted the code to be consistent in output results so I left it in the code.. ALSO, as I understand there could be some minimum deviations when you add or substract values from `floats`, due to floating points handling in the system on CPU instructions level (low-level stuff).. so keep that in mind when using floats :)

p.s. if you are reading this answer and know another approach on how to solve the problem - please attach performance comparison report if possible :)

Comment: That's exactly how I would've done it, except for the fact that you've overwritten Python's `min()` and `max()` functions.

Comment: Alternatively, you could convert the input to an integer first, add and subtract, then convert back to float: `(int(5.86 * 10**4) + 5*10**1 - 10**0) / 10**4 -> 5.8649` whereas `5.86 + 5*10**(-3) - 10**(-4) -> 5.8649000000000004`.